# Typescript infer return object

Tags: typescript

I am creating setup function which looks as follows:

```js
type Setup<T> = (overrideProps?: Partial<T>) => void /* WHAT HERE */;

const setup: Setup<ProductProps> = (overrideProps) => {
  const props: ProductProps = {
    oldPrice: 9000,
    price: 8490,
    ...overrideProps,
  };

  const component = <Product {...props} />;

  return {
     component: testRenderer.create(component),
     props,
  };
};
```

I want to type return value which can be different, but one thing is for sure, function will be returning `props` variable, antoher are optional.

How to type it?

Comment: `Partial<ProductProps>`? or `Partial<T>`?

Comment: But function `setup` can return anything, and I want that VSC would be able to hint that returned object.

Comment: Now that I'm looking on it, the method returns `{ component: ReactComponent (I think), props: Partial<T>`.

Comment: Yes, bu can return `{props, shallowComponent, component, onClickFn}` etc and I would be able to infer this return object and have all type linking and hinting

Comment: `can return`? What do you mean? How?

Comment: `setup` function can have more helpers inside, for example if I am often doing `component.find('Button')` in my jest tests suites I can do it more generic and declare this finding in setup func, then it would return `{ component, props, buttonEl: component.find('Button') }`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189403/discussion-between-mosh-feu-and-rafal-lesniak).